# What do I see on the image when I specify arr[0].imshow(img1[:,:,0]) using slicing ? (imageio package). How to interpret the intensities we observe?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, slice

Please help me to understand what information I see on the image when I use slicing in the imshow() function in the image layers. How to interpret the intensities I see ? And what those colors mean ?

Here is my code:

```py
import imageio as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img1 = io.imread('pexels-asad-photo-maldives-457882.jpg')

fig, arr = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(15,15))

arr[0].imshow(img1[:,:])
arr[0].set_title('img1[:,:]')

arr[1].imshow(img1[:,:,0])
arr[1].set_title('img1[:,:,0]')

arr[2].imshow(img1[:,:,1])
arr[2].set_title('img1[:,:,1]')

arr[3].imshow(img1[:,:,2])
arr[3].set_title('img1[:,:,2]')

plt.show()
```

Image shape : (2624, 3936, 3)

Here is what is displayed:

[image: Output]

Comment: You plot the red, green, and blue channel of your image individually, using some default colormap from Matplotlib. For better understanding, set `arr[x].imshow(img1[:,:,x], cmap='gray')`. Light gray-ish to white-ish pixels indicate high (red, green, or blue) intensity, dark gray-ish to black-ish pixels indicate low (red, green, or blue) intensity. For the sky, for example, you get high intensity in the blue channel (last image).

Comment: Thanks a lot @HansHirse for the reply ! Indeed, it is now clear through plotting it in grayscale. That was my first question why red, green, blue channels are not actually red, green and blue.